# OneSignal not working with Chrome on PC

Tags: php, google-chrome, push-notification, notifications, onesignal

I try to use **OneSignal** for notification to user from my website, It's notification correctly with Firefox(PC), Chrome(Mobile).

But Chrome on PC Not Working and not show anything.

even though I'm subscribed and grant permission of notification completely, But console is show '**Is Completely Subscribed:** **false**' What should I do??

help me please ...

[image]

Comment: Can you paste your code?

Comment: thx for reply, I try using directly by OneSignal in https://onesignal.com before create php code.

Comment: So U mean to say U have checked demo over there by sending push notification ? Am i right?

Comment: yes u right. and it's not work in Chrome browser in PC. are you know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try first sending like this by creating your website name and key over there, I tried and tested it worked for me.

```
<script src="https://cdn.onesignal.com/sdks/OneSignalSDK.js" async=""></script>
<script>
  var OneSignal = window.OneSignal || [];
  OneSignal.push(function() {
    OneSignal.init({
      appId: "***appid******",
    });
  });
</script>
```

See below Image, it worked for me.

[image]

Just in case my Chrome Version is this :

> Version 62.0.3202.94 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: I used that code but not working. that's code in <head> right?

Comment: You can keep that code anywhere,in <head> or even after <body> , not an issue

Comment: If You still can't get it, this is the best example https://github.com/norkunas/onesignal-php-api/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md